# CollapsingToolbarLayout display the incorrect view?

Tags: android

I using CollapsingToolbarLayout  to stretchy image vs Toolbar when Scroll, but when start then layout obscured like below image:
[image]

The left image,when app start, layout **12 Animal** is pull up , I do not want such.

Please for me solution, i want start application show all view on screan like right image.

Thank all!

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    //Container Viewpager
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/activity_maincree_frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:scrollbarSize="50dip"
    app:theme="@style/AppThemeDrawer"
    app:itemBackground="@color/windowBackground"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    android:id="@+id/navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```